# Forward and Backward Pagination in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm using DynamoDB and NodeJS to enlist some objects on the UI. The list is long, and since DynamoDB can scan/query at most 1MB of data at a time, I've decided to use pagination so at the front end I have `Previous` and `Next` buttons to paginate back and forth from the current page.

My problem is I want to retrieve 20 items at a time from `Table X` by using `DynamoDB Query` feature based on a chosen `DynamoDB Index`.
Let's say I've just fetched the initial 20 results (0-20) so on clicking next button I want to fetch results: 21-40 and so on. Also, I want to enable backwards paginating so when I'm on a page which shows results: 41-60, the `Back` button would again fetch results: 21-40.
As per my understanding, DynamoDB doesn't support numerical offset.

How do I implement *backward* and *forward* pagination? I am a newbie in DynamoDB, please help me out.

Comment: For people new here, Optimum pagination strategy to use with dynamodb is - keyset pagination. In short it is difficult to jump from page 1 to page 50. you have to go forward sequentially - lazy loading in websites for example

Answer (score 29):

While DynamoDB will Paginate your data in forward direction only, You'll have to deal with the Backward Pagination in **Front End**.

For large `Tables` (**exceeding 1MB size**), what `DynamoDB` does:

1. Scans or Queries upto 1MB.
2. Returns `LastEvaluatedKey` to fetch the next set of data or the **Next Page**. This value is used as **Pagination Key** in **Front End** to paginate back and forth.

> `LastEvaluatedKey` holds the value of the last object fetched from DynamoDB during a `Scan` or `Query`.

What you need to do (in **Back End**):

1. Use `LIMIT` property of `DynamoDB Query` to specify you want only 20 items.
2. Use `ExclusiveStartKey` property of `DynamoDB Query` to specify that next set of data would start from the specified value of this property.

What you need to do (in **Front End**):

1. Keep an array of objects `arr[]` to host Pagination Keys.
2. Keep a variable `page` initialized to -1, whose value will indicate the current page user is on.
3. Load the initial page of list into the UI. Now alongside the data, if you have `LastEvaluatedKey`, push it into the `arr` and increment `page`.

> Now, you have a single page and `page` indicates you're on
>   **Page 0** and `arr` contains **Page Key** of next page.

4. Code of `Next` Button should follow the logic:

   Request your server to fetch the next page using ExclusiveStartKey = `arr`[`page`]
5. When results of next page arrives, you'll again have another `LastEvaluatedKey`, so again push it into `arr` and increment `page`. So you get the picture here, how we save the **Page Keys**.
6. Code of `Back` Button should follow the logic:

   Since `page` variable indicates the *Current Page* so `page - 1` would indicate the previous page. So: 
   if (`page-1`>=0) Request your server to fetch the next page using ExclusiveStartKey = `arr`[`page - 1`]

You'll have to manage when `Back` & `Next` Buttons are available for clicking by using `arr[]` and `page` variables after each page is fetched.

Comment: how to handle when user click to any page without click next page? example I have 10 page, user don't click next to page 2 though they click page 8 at 2nd, how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

The [pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html) feature in DynamoDB relies on the LastEvaluatedKey. You should be able to do what you want with that and use the page size to always be 20 items. It just won'y be numerical offset per se.

Comment: Ok got it. But how to do backward navigation?

Comment: there is also `ExclusiveStartKey` , also if using index you have `ScanIndexForward`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use page numbers in dynamodb, but for Query (and only for Query) you can move backward using --scan-index-forward option.

> Specifies the order for index traversal: If true (default), the traversal is performed in ascending order; if false , the traversal is performed in descending order.

[AWS DynamoDB CLI query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html)

So you can use LastEvaluatedKey for forward pagination and first key in you data for backward pagination using scan-index-forward option